# Unable to delete files using Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have written the following code to merge and delete the source files,but somehow the source files are not getting deleted.Can any one please throw some light on what i 'm missing here.

```
    public void doDelete(List<String> dID)throws  IOException {

        String DID=null;

        try{
            for( ListIterator<String> iterator = dID.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            {

                DID= (String) iterator.next();

                System.out.println("Deleting PDF" +DID);
                File f =new File("E:\\TestFolder"+ "\\" +DID+".pdf");
                 if (!f.exists()) {
                        System.err.println("File " + f
                            + " not present to begin with!");
                        return;
                      }
                System.out.println(f.length());
                System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                boolean success = f.delete();
                if (!success){
                    System.out.println("Deletion failed.");               
                }else{
                    System.out.println("File deleted."+DID);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();             
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: That is too long for most people to spend time helping you out I'm afraid. Please post shorter examples showing the problem if you would like some help.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of ``System.out.println()``'s. What do they say?

Comment: You post lots of totally irrelevant code. Browsing it briefly, I couldn't find where you actually call doDelete(). Also, please include the (relevant parts of the) output of your program.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR but file deletion failures is usually due to the file still being open.  Especially as you are running it on Windows.
If you would like to get a reason for the delete failure you can use the Java 7 file API instead, it will give you the deletion failure reason as an exception.

```
java.nio.Files.delete(...)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)

Answer (score 0):

In your createFileFromBlob method you are opening multiple FileOutputStreams (for each element of dID.listIterator()) but only closing the last one in your finally block. This will leave an open handle to all files other than the last, preventing them from being deleted as per Pulsar's answer.